# WEKA Decision Tree with String attributes

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, decision-tree

I have an attribute set of 20 with few of them being strings such as codes for states in US, names of subscription plans and and so on. How can we handle string attributes in WEKA for decision tree construction?

I read about stringtowordvector converter, but the strings of each of these attributes is just a word by itself.

Answer (score 1):

You probably figured this out -- you have to declare such "string attributes" (actual string attributes are something else in WEKA) as nominal attributes, i.e., you must declare all the values they can have in the ARFF header in curly brackets.

Comment: Example from the weka manual: 
@ATTRIBUTE class {Iris-setosa,Iris-versicolor,Iris-virginica}

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the attribute following this schema in your ARFF file:

```
@attribute <att_name> string
```

Be careful because `Strings` are stored internally in a string table and represented by
their address in that table. Thus, two strings that contain the same characters will
have the same value.

Source (book): Data Mining: Practical Machine Learning Tools and Techniques 3rd Edition